# Sort posts by activity date

Tags: posts, wp-query

I have a list of posts posted on different dates

I can order the posts by date

```
$loop_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC'    
 )
```

How can I order the post by comment date if the post have a comment.

So sort the posts by activity

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea proposed in [this comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wordpress-austin/XA4kua_Xm4w/lswIyCq4evIJ). Connecting the posts table to the comments table seems like it'd be some super complicated SQL (well all SQL is complicated to me). Instead the link proposes that you add a post meta field to the post to hold the date of the most recent comment.

```
add_action('comment_unapproved_to_approved', 'wpa_144482_comment_approved');

function wpa_144482_comment_approved($comment) {
    $comment_post_ID = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    $date = $comment->comment_date;
    update_post_meta( $comment_post_ID, '_recent_comment_date', $date );
}
```

Then you should be able to sort your posts by the `_recent_comment_date` field.

There is also the [Filter by Comments plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/filter-by-comments/) but it hasn't been updated in a long while so I couldn't vouch for it.

Comment: Do you mean "sort your posts by the `_recent_comment_date` field"?

Comment: Did you test the plugin with the latest version. It hasn't been updated since wordpress 3.1.4, so it might not work

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the plugin. The first suggestion is the same as I would've done.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic yes, I did mean that. Copy/paste fail!

Comment: @PieterGoosen no I haven't tested it. Have updated my answer to include that caveat.

Comment: i guess, there could be a minor issue with the 'recent comment date', say, comment A was posted on 5th May, and comment b was posted on 7th May, and the admin approves Comment B first and then comment A. In this case, the recent comment date would be 5th may insead of 7th

Comment: @helgatheviking Would you be kind enough to give an example of "sort your posts by the _recent_comment_date field"...thanks :)

Comment: Please look into [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) args and ordering by `meta_value` or perhaps `meta_value_num`. There are plenty of examples on this website too. Nothing is different except the meta key is `_recent_comment_date`.