# Query posts by last comments

Tags: wp-query, comments

How to query posts by lastest comment, like what happens here, if some one comment on a post from the dark ages it will popup to the top.

Comment: Something like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/144482/31545)

Answer (score 0):

i thinks this help to you

```
$args = array (
'status' => 'approve',
'number' => '5'
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
if ( !empty( $comments ) ) :
echo '<ul>';
foreach( $comments as $comment ) :
echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID . '">' . $comment->comment_author . ' on ' . get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '</a></li>';
endforeach;
echo '</ul>';
endif;
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?